# Custom UITableViewCell broken when being dragged to reorder

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, drag

I have a custom UITableView subclass that inserts a separator line as a subview, like this:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        CGRect frame = [self bounds];

        frame.origin.y = CGRectGetMaxY(frame) - 1;
        frame.size.height = 1;

        UIView *separator = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];

        [separator setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [separator setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin];

        [self addSubview:separator];
    }
    return self;
}
```

This draws a nice line beneath my cell. However, when the tableview is in edit mode and I drag to reorder the cells, this subview disappears!

Everything else looks the same, and the opacity of the cell is reduced as it is dragged, but why would this subview be removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding drawRect works:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]);
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0, CGRectGetMaxY(rect)-.5, CGRectGetWidth(rect), .5));
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(rect), .5));
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

Comment: So you're just re-creating the line after every move?  (Unfortunately, this doesn't solve _my_ issues with UI controls placed in custom UICells breaking after the move)

Comment: where's your question? I'll take a look at it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571630/rearranging-uitableviewcells-causes-cell-contents-to-break  In my case, rearranging causes the actual cell data to break, and I don't understand all of what is going on.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of adding a separator line as a subview, use the default one that table view comes with and change the borderColor via the cell's backgroundView layer.

```
cell.backgroundView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

`#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` is needed, obviously.

Also, if you're using a grouped table view, make sure to match the outside border:

```
tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

Make sure to the separator line again, of course :) (So *don't* set the tableView separatorStyle property to none: `tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone`)

Comment: Thanks, but the border would go all the way around my cell, not just on the bottom edge. This also requires a backgroundView to be set, so it won't work on unadorned cells.