# Rearranging UITableViewCells causes cell contents to break

Tags: ios, ios5

I have an iOS4 iPad app that I'm upgrading to iOS5, and there is one issue that I don't fully understand what is going on.

The view in question uses a `UITableView` with a number of subclassed `UITableViewCells` to display a series of different (and modifiable) fields.  Each cell contains UI buttons, `UITextFields`, etc etc, and is used to readily store a variable amount of controls.

Via `tableView:canMoveRowAtIndexPath:` we've enabled the ability for the user to rearrange the order of the rows using drag-and-drop.  It worked perfectly in iOS4, but as of iOS5 has ceased to function properly.  A simple swap leaves the moved cell's text fields looking disabled (without their white background), and subsidiary cells further down can become 'bugged', vanishing from the screen in an unpredictable manner -- leaving white spaces where they should be.

What changed between iOS4 and iOS5 that causes this issue, and how can I correct it?

Answer (score 0):

as of iOS 5, you must also implement `tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:` to enable reordering; are you doing this?

Comment: Yes.  Movement appears to be enabled, it's simply corrupting the views.  It's most noticeable when the disparity in cell size (some cells are larger than others) is large.

Comment: Hmm. If you post a screengrab and sample code I'll try to help you out.